# Apache: domains working fine, subdomains not working anymore

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm not sure when, but suddenly subdomains aren't working on my server.

e.g. www.davidlawson.co works, but david.lawson.co isn't working.

```
<VirtualHost 173.203.109.191:80>
        ServerAdmin david@lawson.co

        ServerName david.lawson.co
        ServerAlias davidlawson.co
        ServerAlias www.davidlawson.co

        DocumentRoot /var/www/lawson/david
        <Directory /var/www/lawson/david/>
                Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/lawson/david/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/lawson/david/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions on how to debug this further, or what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Apache server seems to be doing a 301 redirect to www.david.lawson.co which doesn't exist in DNS. Have you added anything to the .htaccess or the site code which would redirect to www.$HOSTNAME?

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]   can I change these to allow specific subdomains?

Comment: You can enter multiple rewrite conditions before the RewriteRule. So for example add: "RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^david\.lawson\.co$" before the first RewriteCond, and the RewriteRule will only trigger if the host is not dave.lawson.co AND it does not start with www.

Comment: !^(www|david)\.